# How can I simultaneously read and write to a binary file?

Tags: c++, logging, memory, binary, fstream

How can I simultaneously read and write to binary files? I cannot seem to figure out why my program is erroring out and every bit of debugging I can think of does not yield me any good results. The program takes a `string` and generates the file information to be written to a binary file. If the log binary exists, then the program compares the information from the file to the information in the log. If the information is different, then the program updates the log. The function I made is below:

```
#define SHADER_LOG "bin\\shader_log.bin"

void checkLog(const std::string& filename) {
    std::string _path = std::filesystem::absolute(".\\shaders\\" + filename).string();
    std::filesystem::file_time_type last_update = std::filesystem::last_write_time(_path);

    std::pair<std::string, std::filesystem::file_time_type> fileInfo{filename, last_update};

    std::cout << "File Info: { " << fileInfo.first << ", " << fileInfo.second << " }\n";

    std::pair<std::string, std::filesystem::file_time_type> log_entry;
    memset(&log_entry, 0, sizeof(log_entry));

    if (!std::filesystem::exists(SHADER_LOG)) {
        std::ofstream log(SHADER_LOG, std::ios_base::out | std::ios::binary);
        log.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&fileInfo), sizeof(fileInfo));
        log.close();
        return;
    }

    std::fstream log(SHADER_LOG, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (!log.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error(std::format("Failed to open {}!", SHADER_LOG));
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (!log.eof()) {
        log.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&log_entry), sizeof(log_entry));
        //log.getline(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&log_entry), sizeof(log_entry));
        i++;
        if ((log_entry.first == fileInfo.first) && (log_entry.second != fileInfo.second))
        {// Update log entry
            log.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&fileInfo), sizeof(fileInfo));
            std::cout << "Log Entry: { " << log_entry.first << ", " << log_entry.second << " }\n";
            std::cout << "Log successfully updated!\n";
        }
        else
        {// Print to manually confirm update status
            std::cout << "Log Entry: { " << log_entry.first << ", " << log_entry.second << " }\n";
            std::cout << std::format("{} is up to date.\n", log_entry.first);
            std::cout << i << std::endl; // debugging number of times the loop is run
        }
    }

    log.close();
    if (!log.is_open()) {
        std::cout << std::format("{} file closed successfully!\n", SHADER_LOG);
    }
        
    return; // trying to debug exiting the function
}
```

On first run, the function seems to work as expected. However, on the second run, the program exits unexpectedly and gives the error code:

```
(process 14128) exited with code -1073741819.
```

After updating the file to be logged, the function exits without the above code, but the informtion printed to the console reveals more information about the problem:

```
Log Entry: { , 1601-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 }
 is up to date.
```

The above is printed some 86 times before the function exits without returning any errors.

I tried condensing the function down to the function below to try and reveal something more about the problem:

```
void checkLog(const std::string& filename) {
    std::string _path = std::filesystem::absolute(".\\shaders\\" + filename).string();
    std::filesystem::file_time_type last_update = std::filesystem::last_write_time(_path);

    std::pair<std::string, std::filesystem::file_time_type> fileInfo{filename, last_update};

    std::cout << "File Info: { " << fileInfo.first << ", " << fileInfo.second << " }\n";

    std::pair<std::string, std::filesystem::file_time_type> log_entry;
    memset(&log_entry, 0, sizeof(log_entry));

    if (!std::filesystem::exists(SHADER_LOG)) {
        std::fstream log(SHADER_LOG, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in | std::ios::binary);
        log.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&fileInfo), sizeof(fileInfo));
        log.seekp(0); // tried .seekp and .seekg
        /* Debugging */
        std::pair<std::string, std::filesystem::file_time_type> log_entry {};
        memset(&log_entry, 0, sizeof(log_entry)); // Read in another stack thread to clear memory to avoid alignment errors
        log.getline(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&log_entry), sizeof(log_entry));
        std::cout << "Log Entry: { " << log_entry.first << ", " << log_entry.second << " }\n";
        log.close();
        return;
    }
}
```

This did give me some more information about what could be causing the problem, but I am still at a loss for the solution. The output of the condensed version indicates that my program is unable to write to the log file:

```
File Info: { shader.comp, 2023-08-15 00:43:48.7875194 }
Log Entry: { , 1601-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 }
 is up to date.
```

Please help me. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and I'm starting to think that it's not possible to read and write to a binary file simultaneously.

Edit:

```
int main() {
    try {
        checkLog("shader.comp");
        std::cout << "Exited Compiler successfully!\n";
        /* When it gives the error code, it does not print the above line to the console */
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I only read far enough to notice there is no function `main`. What driver are you using? Please read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My bad, editing to include the function call rn

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) is worth reading. You also appear the be writing a `std::string` object to the file. This will never work. The object doesn't contain the string data, it is just a few pointers. You need proper serialization.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for the link to an explaination for why `while (!stream.eof())` would not work. That explains why the function prints to the console multiple times in the loop. Does using the `write()` function not automatically convert the data into binary when writing to a binary file, and vice versa for the `read()` function?

Comment: You can't *simultaneously* read and write to a binary file.  The hardware is not set up for this.  There is a "head" on the hard drive that needs to be positioned.  You are either sending current to the head in order to write bits, or you are requesting the head to determine or read the magnetism value.  You *could* change the head or the circuitry to read and then write, but I'm not sure if writing will affect what you have read.  If your read data is in a different location on the drive than the writing data, you really can't do them simultaneously.

Comment: The hard drive is a serial device; only one bit is written at a time in serial fashion (one bit following another).  Your most efficient method of reading or writing is with block mode.  There is an overhead to accessing the drive, whether you are reading one byte or 1 megabyte.  So, a better design would be to read one or more blocks, then write one or more blocks.  I recommend using threads and multiple buffers.  Let one thread start and read at least one buffer, then notify the main thread.  The main thread processes the buffer, then has the write thread process the buffer.

Comment: The `write` function writes raw bytes to a file. That's all. The problem you have is the bytes you are writing are just pointers, not actual string data, and if you read them back you'll end up with a corrupted string object and your program will likely crash.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Could you link an example for how I could pass the actual string data, please? The places I’ve looked so far only show how to write the pointer data.

Comment: If you want to have a fixed size record I'd recommend a struct containing a char array for the string data and whatever else you need. I do not know if `std::filesystem::file_time_type` is a trivial type that can be written and read back successfully, it appear to be implementation defined. I'd store a `uint64_t` with seconds or milliseconds elapsed since a start time depending on the resolution you need. Not a trivial problem without a very clear specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple, fundamental, problems in the shown code. The first one already results in undefined behavior, that pretty much voids the warranty for the rest of the code that follows:

```
memset(&log_entry, 0, sizeof(log_entry));
```

`log_entry` is a `std::pair` that contains a `std::string`.

`memset` can only be used on POD objects. Using it in this kind of a brute-force manner, to nuke an object that's a C++ class, like `std::string`, is undefined behavior.

This kind of `memset` usage is typically seen in C code, to clear out uninitialized memory that holds a `struct`. However this is C++, and not C, and, fortunately, in C++ we don't need to resort to this kind of primitive initialization. This is what constructors and destructors are for, and in C++ we don't do that (unless we really want to do this with POD objects). However, technically this is now undefined behavior, and the observed results from the rest of the code is null and void. But there are some other obvious defects that will also need to be addressed.

```
while (!log.eof()) {
```

This is [a very common bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) that's fully explained by the linked answer.

```
log.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&log_entry), sizeof(log_entry));
```

Our friend `log_entry`, with a `std::string` is back.

`sizeof()` is a ***compile time constant***. It is calculated at compile time. It can't possibly know whether that `std::string` is empty, or it contains the complete contents of the Harry Potter books. The expectation here is that this saves the entire `log_entry` to a file. Clearly, the amount of data that gets written here will vary, depending on the size of the `std::string`.

The shown code appears to assume that the size of each log record is fixed, but if you stop and think, for a moment, then it should become very obvious that this assumption is clearly flawed. The size of each record varies. This, overall, `read()`/`write()` approach is also fundamentally flawed.

```
    if ((log_entry.first == fileInfo.first) && (log_entry.second != fileInfo.second))
        {// Update log entry
            log.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&fileInfo), sizeof(fileInfo));
```

Ignoring the `sizeof` issue and the fact that only POD objects (once more) can be read or written to, in this manner: the apparent intent of the above code is that it replaces the matched entry in the log file with the updated contents.

Unfortunately the existing entry in the log file has been read already. The read/write position, in the file, is now the record that ***comes after it***. And this will, instead, clobber the next record.

However this is a moot point anyway, since this `read()` and `write()` is fundamentally flawed on its own merits. This kind of a `read()`/`write()` pattern is also typical of C code, like `memset()`.

In conclusion, multiple issues must be resolved:

1. Remove and replace all C code that pretends to be C++. Good-bye `memset()`. Reimplement `sizeof()`-based `read()` and `write()` with proper serialization and deserialization. A slightly closer look at the shown code suggests that simple formatted output based operation, using `>>`, should be sufficient. It's already being used for logging to `std::cout`. The same code can be used to format each log entry. Write the filename and the modification time, on their own lines, to the log file, and use `std::getline` to read each one, on the rebound.
2. Fix the record update bug that clobbers the wrong record. Track the file position in the log file, and seek back to the right position before replacing the existing record in the log file.
3. Fix the common logical flaw with loop-based `eof()` checking.

Additionally: it appears that the only reason to go through the trouble of creating all those `std::pair` objects is to make the whole thing fit within the boundaries of the C-style patterns for reading and writing records to a file. Since the C-style pattern is going down the drain anyway, there's no reason to have all these `std::pair` objects creating unneeded complexities. They can be removed as well, and the remaining code simplified.